# Method calling using variable in object name

Tags: c++

I'm trying to increase the ease of use of my project at work. I'm a test engineer, not a programmer. The creator won't give me any source files and said if I had ideas to forward them to him and he will code it. Well, I have a lot of time and I want to learn how my project works under the hood and also save him time. I'll start out by saying I know next to nothing about C++ and honestly don't want to learn an entire language to fix this one issue.

The base functions are load() and start(). There are multiple games on 15 racks.

For instance, if I want to load game3 on rack 2, the current "call" is `game3_rack2_.load();` and `game3_rack2_.start()`

Basically, I want the user to select the rack and game. I'm not super concerned with the game part, but let's say the user inputs rack 6 and this 6 is stored to variable `num`. Is there a simple way to do `game3_rack<num>_.load()` and `game3_rack<num>_.start()` ? I could use if statements, but with the amount of games/racks and multiple calls per game/rack, it seems unfeasible. In another language we have (native to company), the above case works. The variable is evaluated before the statement is executed. I think this is known as reflection? but I'm not entirely sure.

Can I utilize a basic array?

```
game3[N] {game3_rack0_, game3_rack1_, game3_rack2,...game3_rackN};
```

then just call the user input?

```
num = 2; //user wants rack 2
game3[num].load(); game3[num].start(); //loads and starts game3_rack2_
```

Thanks in advance and apologies for my poor understanding of C++.

Comment: Please post the definition of `game3_rack2_`. What is it's type?

Comment: Worst case scenario: Use a scripting language to stamp out code that maps to these variables. Best case: Use `std::map` or instantiate them dynamically. Your array approach could work, but would be annoying if that list keeps changing. That's what scripting can help with.

Comment: Assuming all of the `game3_rackN` are of the same type, or  have a common base class, then you could use a macro to generate your array. Then your `game3[num].load()`, etc. code would work.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] or else this will just be a guessing game.